# Accessing static files from custom template tag

Tags: python, django

In my template I'm trying to add a custom tag that takes an image input, then outputs that image and a class describing whether it is tall or wide.

My code is as follows.

The template:

```
{% load custom_tags %}
{% image_size_class "MANAGEMENT/image.jpg" %}
```

The custom tag:

```
from django import template
from PIL import Image
from django.templatetags.static import static
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def image_size_class(pattern):
    pattern_url = static(pattern)
    img = Image.open(pattern_url)
    width, height = img.size
    if width > height:
        class_tag = "wide"
    else:
        class_tag = "tall"

    return '<img src="' + pattern_url + '"' + '  class="' + class_tag + '">'
```

The desired outcome:

```
<img src="/static/MANAGEMENT/image.jpg" class="wide">
```

What actually happens is I get the error from PIL:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/static/MANAGEMENT/image.jpg'
```

It seems like PIL can't find the file I want it to, but I'm not sure where it is looking! Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is what PIL try to access "/static/" folder on your disk. You should give real path to file, like this:

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
...

@register.simple_tag
def image_size_class(pattern):
    pattern_url = static(pattern)
    file_path = os.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, pattern)
    img = Image.open(file_path)
    width, height = img.size
    if width > height:
        class_tag = "wide"
    else:
        class_tag = "tall"

    return '<img src="' + pattern_url + '"' + '  class="' + class_tag + '">'
```

Comment: I thought as much, I just couldn't find a way of getting it done! Many thanks. I ended up getting the full URL of the image and then using that, but this is much better.